# Clamp player movement correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code to clamp player movement. It works but i have a problem. For example if the player is at position -3.05 and if I hold the button to move left the player still moves over the -3.05 limit to about -3.56. Once i let go of the button it bounces back to -3.05. Same goes for the right side. I do not want it to go over the limits no matter what.

```
Vector3 tmpPos = transform.position;
tmpPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(tmpPos.x, -3.05f, 3.05f);
transform.position = tmpPos;
```

The following is the way i add movement to the player:

```
rigidbody.AddForce (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Instead of using the AddForce to move the object

```
rigidbody.AddForce (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

I use `rigidbody.position` to move the object. I use `Mathf.Clamp` to limit the movement before applying it to `rigidbody.position`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not mix up transform operation with rigidbody unless it's marked isKinematic. So instead of `transform.position`, try clamping `rigidbody.position` inside of `FixedUpdate`.

```
void FixedUpdate(){
  Vector3 pos = rigidbody.position;
  pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, minX, maxX);
  rigidbody.position = pos;
}
```

However, since you're using `AddForce` to move your object, a much simpler way is to make empty game objects with box collider on the left and right of the object, which then will limit your object movement like invisible walls.

Comment: i have tried setting up box colliers on the sides. it works but it isn't perfect either. I see the player object going in to the side walls before bouncing back because it is traveling too fast i guess. So i looked for another solution to which i came across the Mathf.Clamp but this has its own problem. I just need a solution to stop the player in its track without it passing the limit/wall at all and allow it to move the other way.

Comment: @JohnDoe Try it in `Update`, `FixedUpdate` can run zero, one, or several times per frame depending on your frame rate.  Alternatively do a pre-check for distance from the collision point and avoid adding more force if close.  Syncing physics can be tricky.

Comment: @Jerdak How would i go about doing a pre-check?

Comment: @JohnDoe Simple euclidean distance or if you know the direction of movement do a ray cast to find that distance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rigidbody.MovePosition(tmpPos);` instead of setting `transform.position`.